# How to find 52 week high in Python without using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file with daily stock prices with the following columns: Date, Open Price, Close Price, High, Low
I'm trying to add two new columns, 52 week High and 52 week low.
How can I find the 52 week high of each row WITHOUT using pandas?

There are plenty of solutions using pandas, but I'm trying to find a way without pandas.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you do not want to use pandas to achieve this?

Comment: Use another library, like numpy

Comment: @thecruisy - yes - I just want to learn the logic behind finding 52 week highs/lows - i believe the use of a loop is required, but I can't quite figure out how to loop things in a moving, set range. i can loop from the beginning of the file to the end, but I don't know how to move it in a set 52 week range.

Comment: thanks @MadPhysicist - but I don't want to use any libraries, I'm still learning Python and want to understand the logic behind the key concepts. I believe I will need to use a function which can loop thru the data, but I can't quite figure out to restrict it to a set range, like 52 weeks - I can easily find the high and the low for the entire file, but not for the previous 52 weeks

Comment: one logic you can consider is something like, filter the range so that the date is within 52 weeks from today's date, then find the max price. this way, you do not need to do a `for loop`. this is just one way of thinking to simplify your problem